# How to implement t-SNE in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, classification, tsne

I am trying to implement a t-SNE visualization in tensorflow for an image classification task. What I mainly found on the net have all been implemented in Pytorch. See [here](https://learnopencv.com/t-sne-for-feature-visualization/).

Here is my general code for training purposes which works completely fine, just want to add t-SNE visualization to it:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers, Input
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, InputLayer, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, Model
from  matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
from PIL import Image
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, array_to_img, img_to_array, load_img

.
.
.

base_model=tf.keras.applications.ResNet152(
    include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_tensor=None,
    input_shape=None, pooling=None)

.
.
.

base_model.trainable = False


# Create new model on top.
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, 3))
x = base_model(inputs, training=False)



x=keras.layers.Flatten()(x)
x = keras.layers.Dense(64)(x)
x=layers.Activation('relu')(x)

x=keras.layers.Flatten()(x)
x = keras.layers.Dense(32)(x)
x=layers.Activation('relu')(x)

x = keras.layers.Dense(2)(x)
outputs=layers.Activation('softmax')(x)

model=keras.Model(inputs, outputs)



vaidation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=90,
                                     zoom_range=0.2,
                                     horizontal_flip=True, 
                                     vertical_flip=True)


train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_path,  # this is the target directory
        target_size=target_size,  # all images will be resized to the target size
        color_mode='rgb',
        batch_size=batch_size,
        shuffle=True,
        class_mode='categorical',
        interpolation='nearest',
        seed=42)  # since we use binary_crossentropy loss, we need binary labels


validation_generator = vaidation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        validation_path,  # this is the target directory
        target_size=target_size,  # all images will be resized to the target size
        color_mode='rgb',
        batch_size=batch_size,
        shuffle=True,
        class_mode='categorical',
        interpolation='nearest',
        seed=42)


model.compile(optimizer, loss , metrics)

model_checkpoint = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint((model_path+model_filename), monitor='val_loss',verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
model.summary()


history = model.fit(
     train_generator,
     steps_per_epoch = num_of_train_img_raw//batch_size,
     epochs = epochs, 
     validation_data = validation_generator, # relates to the validation data.
     validation_steps = num_of_val_img_raw//batch_size,
     callbacks=[model_checkpoint],
     use_multiprocessing = False)
```

Based on the reference link provided, it seems that I need to first save the features, and from there apply the t-SNE as follows (this part is copied and pasted from [here](https://learnopencv.com/t-sne-for-feature-visualization/)):

```
tsne = TSNE(n_components=2).fit_transform(features)


# scale and move the coordinates so they fit [0; 1] range
def scale_to_01_range(x):
    # compute the distribution range
    value_range = (np.max(x) - np.min(x))

    # move the distribution so that it starts from zero
    # by extracting the minimal value from all its values
    starts_from_zero = x - np.min(x)

    # make the distribution fit [0; 1] by dividing by its range
    return starts_from_zero / value_range

# extract x and y coordinates representing the positions of the images on T-SNE plot
tx = tsne[:, 0]
ty = tsne[:, 1]

tx = scale_to_01_range(tx)
ty = scale_to_01_range(ty)


# initialize a matplotlib plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

# for every class, we'll add a scatter plot separately
for label in colors_per_class:
    # find the samples of the current class in the data
    indices = [i for i, l in enumerate(labels) if l == label]

    # extract the coordinates of the points of this class only
    current_tx = np.take(tx, indices)
    current_ty = np.take(ty, indices)

    # convert the class color to matplotlib format
    color = np.array(colors_per_class[label], dtype=np.float) / 255

    # add a scatter plot with the corresponding color and label
    ax.scatter(current_tx, current_ty, c=color, label=label)

# build a legend using the labels we set previously
ax.legend(loc='best')

# finally, show the plot
plt.show()
```

I would be grateful of your help to connect these two piece.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try something like the following:

**Train your model**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pathlib

dataset_url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz"
data_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file('flower_photos', origin=dataset_url, untar=True)
data_dir = pathlib.Path(data_dir)

batch_size = 32

train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  seed=123,
  image_size=(180, 180),
  batch_size=batch_size)


model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Rescaling(1./255, input_shape=(180, 180, 3)),
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(5)
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
epochs=10
history = model.fit(
  train_ds,
  epochs=epochs
)
```

**Make predictions on last and second last layer of your model and visualize**

```
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
import numpy as np
from  matplotlib import pyplot as plt

model2 = tf.keras.Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=model.layers[-2].output)
test_ds = np.concatenate(list(train_ds.take(5).map(lambda x, y : x))) # get five batches of images and convert to numpy array
features = model2(test_ds)
labels = np.argmax(model(test_ds), axis=-1)
tsne = TSNE(n_components=2).fit_transform(features)

def scale_to_01_range(x):

    value_range = (np.max(x) - np.min(x))
    starts_from_zero = x - np.min(x)
    return starts_from_zero / value_range

tx = tsne[:, 0]
ty = tsne[:, 1]

tx = scale_to_01_range(tx)
ty = scale_to_01_range(ty)

colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'brown', 'yellow']
classes = train_ds.class_names
print(classes)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
for idx, c in enumerate(colors):
    indices = [i for i, l in enumerate(labels) if idx == l]
    current_tx = np.take(tx, indices)
    current_ty = np.take(ty, indices)
    ax.scatter(current_tx, current_ty, c=c, label=classes[idx])

ax.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

[image]

`model2` outputs the features you want to visualize and `model` outputs the predicted classes with the help of `np.argmax`. Also, this example is using a dataset with 5 classes, that is why there are 5 different colors. In your case, you only have 2 classes and therefore 2 colors.

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks very much for your gracious help. It works well on my side.

Two concerns here:
1. I was wondering how come with my ```train_datagen.flow_from_directory(``` the code says:
"AttributeError: 'DirectoryIterator' object has no attribute 'take' "
But with your method of loading data as:
``` train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory( ```

things work well.

Comment: 2. Second concern is I assume only taking 5 batches is not enough, a loop is needed over all batches, right? I tried to implement it as follows:

```for batch in tqdm(train_ds):
    test_ds = np.concatenate(list(train_ds.take(batch).map(lambda x, y : x)))```

However, it shows an error saying: 
" InvalidArgumentError: Shapes of all inputs must match: values[0].shape = [32,224,224,3] != values[1].shape = [32] [Op:Pack] name: count "

Could you please comment on these?
Thanks very much.

Comment: Regarding your second concern, try: `test_ds = np.concatenate(list(train_ds.map(lambda x, y : x)))`… you do not have to use `take`

Comment: If you wanna use `take` in your case. Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69752833/imagedatagenerator-that-outputs-patches-instead-of-full-image/69755698#69755698

Comment: Thanks much for the help. It works without `take`, but I get a gpu computation limitation error. Is it standard to show the t-SNE visualization on only a few images (thus a few batches), or on all dataset images?

Comment: Try a few images

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243032/discussion-between-seyed-and-alonetogether).